# 日本語に違和感:書式設定の方法

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

以下の日本語に違和感があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私なら以下のように訳します。

```
文章の整え方
段落わけには、改行を使用します
改行には、半角スペースを2個追加します
斜体、太字には文字を__、**で囲みます
引用には行の先頭に>を付加します
〜省略〜
文章の整え方についてのヘルプ
質問についてのヘルプ
```

Answer (score 1):

keiminaの案は下記に修正しました。「_」は日本語で使えない為、「*」になります。下記の日本語に問題なかったら、明日適用します。

**文章の整え方**

- 段落わけには、改行を使用します
- 改行には、半角スペースを2個追加します
- 斜体、太字には文字を**テキスト**、****テキスト****で囲みます
- 引用には行の先頭に>を付加します

〜省略〜

文章の整え方についてのヘルプ
質問についてのヘルプ